# gh-pages with static html can't access file when it exists

Tags: html, github, http-status-code-404, relative-path, github-pages

The [index.html](https://a-lucas.github.io/simple-url-cache/) home page displays fine, however any any link will throw a 404.

The static website has folder with html in it, index link to these html with the correct path, but displays a 404.

When clicking on [this link](https://a-lucas.github.io/simple-url-cache/modules/_cacheengine_.html), I got a 404.

however the file is present as you [can see here](https://github.com/a-lucas/simple-url-cache/tree/gh-pages/modules) .

I am really banging my head on a simple html pb, which is frustrating.

Comment: the problem is the next. Your files under folder are not assigned to gh-pages

Comment: Is it possible to assign them to gh-pages? They are on the gh-pages branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself and finally discovered a simpler solution.  The problem is that [Jekyll ignores all files that start with _](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/).  The simple solution is to add a `.nojekyll` file to your docs dir.

My docs script looks like this:

`"rimraf ./docs && typedoc src/ --out docs --mode modules --module commonjs --target es6 --excludePrivate && touch ./docs/.nojekyll && gh-pages -d docs -t"`

`touch` is an npm module that creates the file and the `-t` flag on `gh-pages` is necessary to have that dot file uploaded.

Comment: True but I prefer the crossplatform solution; especially when it's little extra work.

Comment: But I don't use Jekyll. I built my project with Webpack. I didn't upload any folder starts with `_`. What's the solution in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Alright I though I might just answer my own question here.

Github Page doesn't allow several static HTML files.

This is not very clear to be honest on their docs, but the solution is quite simple :

Assuming your local static docs works correctly, just follow these steps :

#### install jekyll

`gem install jekyll bundler`

#### add a file _config.yml

in your `docs` or on the root of your `gh-pages` branch with this content:

`auto: true`

#### execute `jekyll serve`

And test if this works ok on the url outputed in your console

#### add `_site` in your .gitignore

#### push and bingo!

If you are like me using [typedoc](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc) to compile typescript into nice documentation, you will run into trouble.

Because Jekyll automatically exclude from the build any files starting with `_`, and typedoc generates ONLY that, I wrote a [simple yeoman generator](https://github.com/a-lucas/typedoc2jekyll) that does all the replacement for you.